# Excel Macro - Trying to grab 5 rows place in 5 horizontal spaces and stack on top of each other

Tags: excel, vba

I have one column of data which has 1 word translated under it 4 times. Then this repeats all down the column. What I want to have is 4 columns with each language translation in each one. They are stacked on top of each other at the moment. I have tried a Macro but can't seem to get it to loop.

```
Range("B3").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("C2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B4").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("D2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B5").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("E2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B6").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("B3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B7").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("C3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B8").Select
Selection.Cut
```

Is it best to use cut and then move the first column up and repeat the same action?

Attached image of data on left and how it should look on right. Appreciate any pointers, thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pretending for a moment that the languages are in order, a few different ways of doing things:

1) Formulas - `=Index(A:A,Row()*4+1)` (Change the 1 to 2, 3, 4 depending)

2) VBA simple loop basics-

```
For i = 2 to LastRowA
    if i mod 4 = 1 then
          LastRowB = 'LastRow for column B
          ws.range("B" & LastRowB + 1) = ws.range("A" & i)
     else if i mod 4 = 2 then
           LastRowC = 'LastRow for column B
          ws.range("C" & LastRowC + 1) = ws.range("A" & i)
     else if i mod 4 = 3 then
          LastRowD = 'LastRow for column B
          ws.range("D" & LastRowD + 1) = ws.range("A" & i)
     else if i mod 4 = 0 then
          LastRowE = 'LastRow for column B
          ws.range("E" & LastRowE + 1) = ws.range("A" & i)
     End if


Next i
```

Note that this is just the rough structure of a conditional loop like this - further tweaking and editing is needed for the syntax (and some research on how to find lastrow)

I recommend the formulaic method.

Also note: The methods I listed will preserve the original data, which is my preference when doing this type of work. It lets you get a free "Do over" if there's any mistakes.